# Recursion not entering base case

Tags: python, recursion

when i run this program i am getting index out of range error. what i did wrong why it's not working

```
def knapsack(p, w, capacity, idx):
    if capacity <= 0 or 0 > idx >= len(p):
        return 0
    profit_1 = 0
    if w[idx] <= capacity:
        profit_1 = p[idx] + knapsack(p, w, capacity - w[idx], idx + 1)
    profit_2 = knapsack(p, w, capacity, idx + 1)
    return max(profit_1, profit_2)


p = [31, 26, 72, 17]
w = [3, 1 , 5, 2]

print(knapsack(p, w, 7, 0))
```

It's not entering base case

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(knapsack(p, w, 7, 0))
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 6, in knapsack
    profit_1 = p[idx] + knapsack(p, w, capacity - w[idx], idx + 1)
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 6, in knapsack
    profit_1 = p[idx] + knapsack(p, w, capacity - w[idx], idx + 1)
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 7, in knapsack
    profit_2 = knapsack(p, w, capacity, idx + 1)
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 6, in knapsack
    profit_1 = p[idx] + knapsack(p, w, capacity - w[idx], idx + 1)
  File "C:/Users/komat/PycharmProjects/DSA/divide&conquer/knapsack.py", line 5, in knapsack
    if w[idx] <= capacity:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace to know where you get index out of range?

Comment: You're checking for `len(p)`, but you use `w[idx]` without a range check...?

Comment: this line is the problem `0 > idx >= len(p)`

Comment: You should do `capacity <= 0 or idx < 0 or len(p) <= idx`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing idx + 1 in the line `profit_1 = p[idx] + knapsack(p, w, capacity - w[idx], idx + 1)`. In some iteration, idx becomes 3 and idx + 1 becomes 4. However length of arrays are 4 and index of 4 won't work as indexing starts from 0 and ends at 3. Hence it breaks with IndexError.

Try adding `print (p, w, capacity, idx)` as the first line of your function def and you'll know where it breaks.

Comment: I written same code in java it's working in python it's not working